# What is the tense ot the sentence "The problem has been solved"

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

1) I always use the sentence "The problem has been solved" at my work but now I want to be sure my usage is correct. From my point of view, this tense is the present perfect, am I right?

2) Can I use the word "solved" if the main tense is the present perfect?

3) Shall I use "The problem is solved" instead of "The problem has been solved"?

Comment: I don't understand your #2

Comment: "The problem has been solved" is the present perfect tense in the passive voice (it has been solved by someone). In "The problem is solved", "solved" is an adjective describing a state in the present tense. I don't understand your question 2).

Comment: Many people would delete to 'Problem solved'.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I wanted to say if the word "solved" can be put in a sentence where the tense is Present Perfect. @BillJ I think "solved" is also an adjective describing a state in the Present Perfect. Am I right?

Comment: Don't get bogged down: I have solved OR I solved the problem. I solve problems everyday. Problems are solved by me everyday. A problem is solved by me everyday. Examples are easier than nomenclature and this question should be on the ELL site.

Comment: Your only tensed verb there is *has*, which is in the present tense not the past tense. What are you actually asking? *Been* and *solved* are both participial inflections but not here finite verbs.

Answer (score 1):

1.Yeah,it's just the passive form of Present Perfect.

2.For sure,you can.
I have completed the task.
The task has been completed (by me).
Or: I have solved the problem.

3.That refers to more Present Simple,as you see.
The problem is solved=The problem is always solved by someone.

Or "solved" can be used as an adjective,as well.(Having a solution, having been explained or answered).
That is a solved problem.

Though,I'm not sure if it really makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, "has been" is the present perfect tense of "to be". That is the verb in the sentence.

"Solved" is not part of the verb. It is a participial adjective -- a principal verb form that is used as an adjective.

The sentence is in passive voice, which means that the subject of the sentence, "the problem", is not doing the acting, but is being acted upon. "Solved", in this case is a predicate adjective that describes the subject, which is "the problem". It functions just like any other adjective would. It therefore doesn't have any incidence on the tense of the verb that is used.

If you changed to active voice, as in "I have solved the problem," then "solve" becomes the verb. But that's a whole different discussion. Passive voice changes the landscape.